# Getting Mxnet Installation issue on MacBook Pro (M1 Chip)

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, computer-vision, mxnet

I am using MacBook Pro with M1 Chip (2020). I tried to install `mxnet` on jupyter notebook (miniforge) using the following command:

`!pip3 install mxnet opencv-python`

After running the command, it installed mxnet version `1.6.0`.

```
Requirement already satisfied: mxnet in /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/python_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages (1.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: opencv-python in /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/python_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages (4.5.5.64)
```

But when I tried to run `im2rec` to generate list files for the training dataset (90%) and the validation dataset (10%) [Reference: Sagemaker book by Julien Simon]

`!python3 im2rec.py --list --recursive --train-ratio 0.9 dogscats .`

I got this error:

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmysB.jpg)

After that I uninstalled the `mxnet` using `pip uninstall mxnet` and clone `mxnet` repo from [github](https://github.com/apache/incubator-mxnet), I was able to run the above command.

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZPHk.png)

When I run this command:

`!python3 im2rec.py --num-thread 8 dogscats .`

I got the following error:

> record = mx.recordio.MXIndexedRecordIO(os.path.join(working_dir,
> fname_idx), AttributeError: module 'mxnet' has no attribute 'recordio'

Could anyone please guide me how to install mxnet using GPU support on Macbook Pro with M1 Chip Processor?